# can't implement matrices and vectors using GADTs in haskell

Tags: haskell, vector

I am a beginner to Haskell.
I was trying to implement Matrices and Vectors in haskell. I wanted these to support all types in Num typeclass, but not others so i tried using GADTs but i am getting errors can you explain why i am getting errors. Or can i get the same functionality without this way.

My code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

class LStruct s where
  scale :: (Num a) => a -> s -> s
  add :: s -> s -> s


data Vector a where
  Vector :: (Num a) => a -> Vector [a]

data Matrix a where
  Matrix :: (Num a) => a -> Matrix [a]


instance LStruct (Vector a) where
  scale a (Vector xs) = Vector (map (*a) xs)
  add (Vector xs) (Vector ys) = Vector (zipWith (+) xs ys)
```

error:

```
[-Wdeferred-type-errors]
• Could not deduce: a2 ~ [a1]
  from the context: (a ~ [a2], Num a2)
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Vector :: forall a. Num a => a -> Vector [a],
             in an equation for ‘scale’
    at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:20:12-20
  ‘a2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Vector :: forall a. Num a => a -> Vector [a],
    in an equation for ‘scale’
    at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:20:12-20
• In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘xs’
  In the first argument of ‘Vector’, namely ‘(map (* a) xs)’
  In the expression: Vector (map (* a) xs)
• Relevant bindings include
    xs :: a2
      (bound at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:20:19)
    a :: a1
      (bound at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:20:9)
    scale :: a1 -> Vector a -> Vector a
      (bound at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:20:3)

[-Wdeferred-type-errors]
• Could not deduce: a2 ~ [c0]
  from the context: (a ~ [a1], Num a1)
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Vector :: forall a. Num a => a -> Vector [a],
             in an equation for ‘add’
    at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:21:8-16
  or from: (a ~ [a2], Num a2)
    bound by a pattern with constructor:
               Vector :: forall a. Num a => a -> Vector [a],
             in an equation for ‘add’
    at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-       TEMP.hs:21:20-28
  ‘a2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Vector :: forall a. Num a => a -> Vector [a],
    in an equation for ‘add’
    at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:21:20-28
  Expected type: [c0]
    Actual type: a1
• In the second argument of ‘zipWith’, namely ‘xs’
  In the first argument of ‘Vector’, namely ‘(zipWith (+) xs ys)’
  In the expression: Vector (zipWith (+) xs ys)
• Relevant bindings include
    ys :: a2
      (bound at /home/d4rk0wl/Playground/hs/Mask/.stack-work/intero/intero10129CJD-TEMP.hs:21:27)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you intended to write:

```
data Vector a where
    Vector :: (Num a) => [a] -> Vector a
```

"A Vector or a's can be constructed from a list of a's"

The version in your question takes a single `a`, and the errors you are getting are about GHC trying to map over that single value.

More broadly, I would recommend moving the `Num` constraint from the constructor to the instances and functions that use `Vector`.  Code written this way seems to get better error messages from GHC, and is easier to work with.  I'm not sure if there's a deep reason for this, or if it's just a question of where GHC devs have spent time.

So the instance declaration might become:

```
instance Num a => LStruct (Vector a) where
```

and the instance body can stay the same.